How to schedule custom command that executes every hour
I created a custom command to print logs.
Now I want to schedule that command to execute every hour.
Can any one give me a step-by-step process to achieve that? I am new to craft CMS.
Craft CMS version: 3.9
Here is my command file:
File path: modules/customcommand/src/console/controllers/CronSchedulerController.php
<?php

namespace modules\customcommand\console\controllers;

use Craft;
use craft\console\Controller;

class CronSchedulerController extends Controller
{
    public $defaultAction = 'handler';

    public function actionHandler(): int
    {
        Craft::info('Cron Schedule custom executed', 'cron_scheduler_command');
        // my other stuff...
        return 0;
    }
}

Executing commands using the command line is working properly:
php craft custom-command/cron-scheduler


The Craft CLI can be invoked from CRON just like any other binary on your system! Keep in mind that the command will be run by whatever user triggers the task—so that may not be the same user as the HTTP or PHP-FPM processes run as.
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/env php /path/to/craft custom-command/cron-scheduler

Check out Crontab Guru if the CRON syntax gives you any trouble. We also have a bit about invoking CLI commands with CRON in the Queue Runners section of the documentation.
